# Methods of blocking websites on linux (except /etc/hosts)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

Long time ago I blocked list of webpages using different methods. Now I would like to whitelist one of these adresses, unfortunatelly I don't rember how I blocked it. I have deleted one line from /etc/hosts, but after restart, the page is still blocked.

I am sure that I was modyfying one more file besides /etc/hosts.

Could you help me?

Comment: Did you create a firewall rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables is the defacto firewall for the linux operating systems.

Many linux versions have a something like firewalld or similiar, but in fact its just a program that creates iptable rules in the background.

```
iptables --list
```

Should list all the rules.  However you need to find the local tool, otherwise when rebooting the changes will revert.

In Ubuntu it maybe called UFW.  I have never used UFW myself, but I suspect their is a /etc/ufw.conf or /etc/ufw/ufw.conf or something like that.